# Recompile R with PNG support

Tags: linux, r, png, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am running R 3.1.2 on a headless Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian. Packages install fine, but I can't save PNGs. After googling the error for a long time, I found [this response](https://superuser.com/questions/603744/why-is-r-having-trouble-rendering-plots-to-a-png-file), which says I need to "manually recompile R with explicit PNG support."

I apologize if this is a basic question, but how do I recompile R with PNG support? If it's helpful, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309891/install-r-3-1-2-on-wheezy-7-8-raspbian-fails) is how I installed in the first place. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dirk, who correctly diagnosed this as a problem of running R headless on the pi, I found a solution by mixing answers from previous posts:

- I start R by calling `xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" sudo R`
- I installed the `Cairo` package in R and save plots using code I adapted from [this blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/exporting-nice-plots-in-r/)

I also found [this site](https://www.labkey.org/wiki/home/Documentation/page.view?name=rconfig) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

What does `capabilities()["png"]` say?  I suspect it says `TRUE` as I see no reason why your Raspian package should not follow the standard configuration of both the R source defaults as well as the Debian package default.

Comment: Thanks for responding. `png` `jpg` `x11` and `cairo` are all `FALSE`. I remember getting an error while installing the 'jpeg' package, which I fixed by `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`. Maybe that's a clue?

Comment: Ok, now we have that confirmed. Come to think about it, this makes sense as R is _headless_ per your post, hence no X11 and hence no font metrics and no device.  You can get png et al if you wrap a headless R inside of `xvfb-run` (if Raspian has that; see some other answers here).  Otherwise try one of the add-on cairo device packages for headless plotting.

Comment: Thanks, I will try `xvfb-run`. My ultimate goal is to use cron to call an Rscript that crunches data and outputs a plot. Is it still considered _headless_ if I call the Rscript through a timed cron job instead of manually through SSH? Would that make a difference? Again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, the definition of _headless_ is _no `DISPLAY` variable_ which is pretty  much guaranteed under `cron`.  But that is an almost-FAQ, now that you know what to look for you can get this fixed. It has noting to do with Raspian---you'd have the _exact same issue_ with an amd64 desktop or server.

Comment: Also see [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999983/) with an alternative.

Comment: thanks for answering my dumb question about cron. I tried `xvrb-run` with and without the server-args. I still get `Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
  unable to start device PNG` and `In grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  :
  could not open PNG file '/myfile.png'`. I'm guessing recompiling will not help.

Comment: Err, `/myfile.png` will **never** work unless you are `root`. Did you mean `/tmp/myfile.png`?

Comment: sorry, I just shortened the file path to make the comment easier to read (but added confusion). It's more like `/home/pi/Github/myrepository/myfile.png`